# Showing a sequence DIVERGES using the Cauchy Criterion.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to show that the sequence $(cos(k\pi/2), sin(k\pi/2))$ converges or diverges and then prove it.

From inspection I can tell that it diverges since each of the individual components diverge (more specifically they all bounce around their respective amplitudes).

So I need to prove it diverges, using the cauchy criterion.

That is, for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $m, n, N \in \mathbb{N} \gt 0$ such that if $m,n \gt N$ then $||x_m - x_n|| \geq \epsilon$.

So I have that

$||cos(k\pi/2) - sin(k\pi/2)||$ ... and I am stuck how to proceed from here. Any tips? Algebraic identities? I'm not sure how I can get something useful.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you doing ? .. $\|x_m-x_n\| = \|(\cos(m\pi/2),\sin(m\pi/2)),-(\cos(n\pi/2),\sin(n\pi/2))\| =|\cos(m\pi/2)-\cos(n\pi/2)|+|\sin(m\pi/2)-\sin(n\pi/2)|$

Comment: Try negating the sentence: *there exists* $\epsilon > 0$ such that *for all* $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist $m,n$ such that $m, n > N$ and $|| x_m - x_n || > \epsilon$

Comment: and no, the Cauchy criterion for convergence is "for every $\epsilon > 0$ there  exists $N$ such that for every $m > n  \ge N $ we have $\|x_m-x_n\|< \epsilon$". The negation of that is "there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $N$, there exists $m > n \ge N$ with $ \|x_m-x_n\|\ge \epsilon$

Comment: if $x_1 = (\cos \frac \pi2, \sin \frac \pi2) = (0,1)$, and $x_2 = (\cos \pi, \sin  \pi)=(-1,0)$ then $\|x_2-x_1\| =  \sqrt{2}$.  What does $\|x_{k+1} - x_k\|$ equal?